# How to use a Normal Distribution with numpy or scipy which, in addition to the mean and standard deviation, also uses the minimum and maximum value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy

I would need to use normal distribution with Python. I don't care about graphs, i just want to understand how to apply it in numpy or scipy. Is there any solution to apply the logic of my exercise to numpy, scipy or similar?

I looked for different solutions on Stackoverflow and on the web, but none of them correspond to what I'm looking for, because most of the results on the web report average and standard deviation, while i have: `average`, `standard deviation`, and also a `minimum value` and a `maximum value`.

I show as an example the problem (already SOLVED, i'm not looking for the solution) whose application I'm looking for with numpy or scipy (I repeat, I don't need to draw graphs).

**Problem** - Assuming that the distribution of weights of individuals in a population is Gaussian with `mean µ = 61` kg and `standard deviation σ = 5` kg

Calculate the percentage of individuals whose weight is `between 59` kg and `63` kg

Solution:

```
[59, 63] = [(61− 0.4 * 5), (61 + 0.4 * 5)] = [59,63]
0.4 = 0.3108
0.3108 = 31%
```

In the appropriate statistic table, `0.4` and `0.4` correspond to `0.3108` in the range. So the final result, that is, the percentage of individuals whose weight is between 59 kg and 63 kg, will be `31%`

Comment: Maybe this question is of help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482730/how-to-find-areas-under-the-normal-curve

Comment: @Parham I do not believe. I don't need mathematical or statistical solutions. I wrote the math problem (which is SOLVED) just as an example to understand what i need with Numpy or Scipy :)

Comment: Are you not looking for a programmatic solution to calculating the area under the curve?

Comment: The general answer for probability is they area under the curve, so the answer @Parham references IS the solution.  See the formula at the end of the ansswer.

Comment: In your "solution" somewhere you need to get the 0.4 -> 0.3108 mapping.  That is what the CDF gets you.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, in my "solution" I have to manually get the 0.4 -> 0.3108 mapping. In Parham's kind solution, then the mapping is derived automatically with scipy.stats.norm.cdf. Well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure of my statistical coding but based on [this Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/482737/228612) I believe this will do the trick:

```
import scipy
MEAN = 61
STD = 5

a_b = (59, 63)
percentage = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(a_b[1], loc=MEAN, scale=STD)-scipy.stats.norm.cdf(a_b[0], loc=MEAN, scale=STD)

print(percentage)
```

Outputs:

```
0.31084348322064836
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your answer, but the final result is right (0.3108). So I think your answer is right. I also want to wait for someone else's comment, but I think your answer is correct. In the meantime I voted for you. Thanks :)

Comment: A curiosity, please: in case I didn't want to use "between", but if I only wanted to use "> 59" and therefore wanted to remove 63, how could I do it?

Comment: That would be `1-scipy.stats.norm.cdf(59, loc=MEAN, scale=STD))` I believe :)

Comment: Ok, fine, thanks. But in your main solution code is >= 1? I wondered if 1 was also "equal to 1" and not just > 1

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I am following, @Horiatiki, but the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) returns a probability, therefore at most 1. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself poorly. I wrote it wrong. Instead of 1 I wanted to write 59. In your solution, there is a_b=(59,63), so my doubt concerns the "beetween": I was wondering if the comparison also included a value EQUAL to 59, therefore >= 59, or directly > 59

Comment: The CDF evaluated at point _x_ is defined as the probability that a random value is _less than or equal_  to _x_ so `1-CDF(59)` (sloppy CDF notation ) would be strictly larger > 59 I believe!

Answer (score 2):

Parham's answer is probably the most efficient and easily-read one. But your calculation can also be done using the error function erf(x) in the math module if you don't want to use either numpy or scipy.

Again, it uses the difference of the two cumulative density functions (cdf) to find "probability between" two values.

Also converted to a percentage.

```
import math

def cdf( x, mu, sigma ):
    return 0.5 * ( 1 + math.erf( ( x - mu ) / ( sigma * math.sqrt( 2.0 ) ) ) )

mean, sd = 61.0, 5.0
percentage = 100.0 * ( cdf( 63.0, mean, sd ) - cdf( 59.0, mean, sd ) )
print( "Percentage = {:8.2f}".format( percentage ) )
```

Output:

```
Percentage =    31.08
```

Comment: Your answer is very interesting, thank you. Voted